# .Rhistory file not loaded at startup

Tags: r

Here is how I start **R** on my linux machine.

**.Rprofile** is at the root of my **$HOME** directory and has only this line:

```
source ("~/.config/r/Renviron.r")
```

Then I append all kind of options,user environment variable paths,functions or aliases in my **Renviron.r** file. Among other lines, this one set the path to Rhistory :

```
Sys.setenv(R_HISTFILE="/developement/language/r/.Rhistory")
```

The path is correct, as returned by command

```
R > Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")
```

Following this [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), it seems there is no need to tell R explicitly to load history (loadhistory("path/to/HISTFILE"). When I run **R** on my terminal, there is no history.

What am I doing wrong ?  Thank you for help

Comment: Did you wrap your `source()` in a `.First` function in your `.Rprofile` ?

Comment: What happens if you use the default .Rprofile the R-installer generates?  Are you certain your particular 'flavor' of terminal session supports history?

Comment: Looking at [`?history`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/savehistory) I saw that you can edit in your .Rprofile file the functions `.First` and `.Last` in combination with `savehistory` and `loadhistory` (look at the example at the end of the link). I guess is not the same as what you wanted, but it should work.

Comment: I didn't wrap my source in .First. my .First () shall only be something to source all my function placed in one directory, something like sourceDirectory("path/to/my/functions.r")

Comment: I can of course add loadhistory("path/to/R_HISTFILE") in Renvironr, but what puzzles me is that the R_HISTFILE variable is correctly set but not used.My terminal is urxvt with zsh and supports history, at least for my linux commands.

Comment: Just a stupid guess: Is there a typo in the path you use for setenv? Is your real path name development/... instead of developement/...?

Comment: Not so stupid, as typo are wasting my time ! But in this case, no. During my R session, running > loadhistory("R_HISTFILE") in fact empty my session history. R is acting like it is loading an empty file :-(

Comment: Well, what's in `R_HISTFILE`, which is the filename you asked for there?  And is it in your current working directory?

Comment: R_HISTFILE is a list of previous commands, one command per line.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the R documentation on how to load the history is not updated or correct. Apparently the only way to get it to work is by using the `utils::` hook for the library that contain the `loadhistory()` function. In your `.Rprofile`, add the line like this:

```
if(interactive()) try(utils::loadhistory(file="C:/pathto/home/xxxx/.Rhistory"))
```

Trying to load this without the hook, results in a "*function not found*" error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why I couldn't load my HISTFILE.This file had to be renamed with at least one letter before **.Rhistory**.

```
> loadhistory("path/to/.Rhistory") # loads no commands
> loadhistory("path/to/R.Rhistory") # loads indeed command history
```

Comment: That seems odd, unless you have some sort of strict "ignore invisible files" set in your Linux environment.  What happens if you try an escape, such as `loadhistory("path/to/\.Rhistory")` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `\.` is not a recognized escape.